# PyAMF: How do you get the client's ip address?

Tags: python, flash, pyamf

Is there anyway to get the client's ip address when running PyAMF via the WSGI gateway interface (Apache)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be under the key `REMOTE_ADDR` in your server's request handler. For example, (from the [Hello World](http://www.pyamf.org/tutorials/general/helloworld/index.html) script):

```
httpd = simple_server.WSGIServer(
    ('localhost', 8000),
    simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler,
)

def app(environ, start_response):
    # environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] is what you're looking for!
    pass

httpd.set_app(app)
```